# Timeout expired when Starting without debugging, but works fine while debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a simple C# Windows Forms application I'm trying to create. on `Form1_Load` I query my database with a simple request to fill a DataGridView.

If I debug the application, the query executes immediately without issue.

If I "Start without debugging," the connection to the database times out every time with SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

This is affecting multiple different projects which used to work flawlessly before today, <s>so I'm pretty certain it's an issue with Visual Studio and not my code.</s> Here's hoping someone knows what could be causing this.

After a fresh install of VS2008 on a new machine, I'm still experiencing the issue. I was able to run the project without debugging, and the first time connecting to the database worked fine, but now it always fails as described above. Possibly some kind of weird connection pool issue in VS?

Answer (score 0):

Check your antivirus software.

My antivirus was flagging every new application I tried to run without debugging, but I had alerts for my antivirus turned off so I had no idea.

I turned on alerts and suddenly when I ran my app I got a notice from my antivirus. I just allowed it permanently and now everything runs smoothly.